# Swashbuckle/Swagger schema shows read only properties in schema on PUT operation

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, readonly-attribute

I have a simple model that has the property **Agg2Id_Agg2Reference** as only having a public getter yet it still shows up in the schema Post operation within Swagger UI via latest version of Swashbuckle.

The following is the model class...

```
 public class UpdateRequest
{
    private string _firstProperty;
    private string _agg2_ServiceEndPoint;
    private AEA.GarthApp.Service2.Agg2.ViewModels.Agg2 _agg2Id_Agg2Reference;
    private AEA.GarthApp.Service2.Agg2.ViewModels.Agg2Id _agg2Id;
    private AEA.GarthApp.Service1.Agg1.ViewModels.Agg1Id _agg1Id;
    public void SetAgg2ServiceEndPoint(string value)
    {
        _agg2_ServiceEndPoint = value;
    }

    public void SetAgg2IdAgg2Reference(AEA.GarthApp.Service2.Agg2.ViewModels.Agg2 value)
    {
        _agg2Id_Agg2Reference = value;
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string FirstProperty
    {
        get => _firstProperty;
        set => _firstProperty = value;
    }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Agg2_ServiceEndPoint
    {
        get => _agg2_ServiceEndPoint;
    }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public AEA.GarthApp.Service2.Agg2.ViewModels.Agg2 Agg2Id_Agg2Reference
    {
        get => _agg2Id_Agg2Reference;
    }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public AEA.GarthApp.Service2.Agg2.ViewModels.Agg2Id Agg2Id
    {
        get => _agg2Id;
        set => _agg2Id = value;
    }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public AEA.GarthApp.Service1.Agg1.ViewModels.Agg1Id Agg1Id
    {
        get => _agg1Id;
        set => _agg1Id = value;
    }
}
```

The following is shown in Swagger UI...

[image]

NOTE 1 : I tried to decorate the property **Agg2Id_Agg2Reference** with and without [**ReadOnly**(true)] attribute yet still I see this property show up in Swagger UI.

NOTE 2 : The string type property **Agg2_ServiceEndPoint** is also only a getter yet it does not show up in the UI schema (as expected).

NOTE 3 : I don't wish to decorate with **JsonIgnore** as I actually want this data down on the client, I just don't want to show it as a settable property in the Swagger UI schema.

How can I remove the property **Agg2Id_Agg2Reference** from showing up in the Swagger/OpenAPI schema and not show up in Swagger UI?

Answer (score 0):

The above class is the output of my code-generator product and I just realized that this particular command doesn't require the Agg2Id_Agg2Reference property at all so the answer to this question is no longer required ....  that said I wouldn't mind to learn why that property was showing up.